# Looking for a Way to Loop Until value of TCP Packet = 1

Tags: vb.net, tcp, visual-studio-2019, do-loops

I am trying to trigger a given function off of a static TCP port number. When the port number receives a packet of Value = 1 it will then trigger an internal function.

```
    strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
    strIPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()
    Dim IP As System.Net.IPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(strIPAddress)
    Dim PortNO As Integer = 5040
    Dim MyData As String = ""
    Dim LabView_TriggerValue As Integer = 1
    Try
        Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient(IP.ToString, PortNO)
        Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(9998) {}
        Dim responseData As String = String.Empty
        Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
        stream.ReadTimeout = 1000
        Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
        MyData = responseData.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
        MessageBox.Show(responseData)
        'Return MyData
        Do
        Loop Until responseData = LabView_TriggerValue
        stream.Close()
        client.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = "" & ex.Message
    End Try
```

I am running into a problem where my Do...Loop Until call-out is not looping. The code runs regardless of the value on Port 5040. Ideally it should keep looping.refreshing the port 5040 until it receives a packet with value of integer = 1.

Comment: How can your loop be useful when `responseData` doesn't change inside it?

Comment: You might be looking for `Await`.

Comment: Maybe you're porting code from a C-heritage language where assignment is an expression (and thus the condition `responseData = labView_TriggerValue` will both assign and return the assigned value)?  VB doesn't work that way.  In an expression context, `=` is exclusively a comparison operator and does not assign.